# Compiling Mysqldb for jython 2.5 on Solaris

Tags: python, mysql, solaris, driver, jython

I have used python2.6 + MySQL on Windows and there are binaries available.

I wanted to get the whole thing working on `Solaris`

Hence got the Mysql-Python package from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

I had to get the setuptools installed which is done.
Exploded the **MySQL-python-1.2.3c1**

When I  this
`/jython2.5.1/jython setup.py build`

Error -

```
`File "/opt/somepath/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/setup_windows.py", line 2, in get_config
import os, sys, _winreg
ImportError: No module named _winreg`
```

I don't understand why it would require windows.py. Either I'm using the incorrect code or I'm not passing the correct flags. Or I'm going on a tangent somewhere else 8-)

Sorry, this is the first time I'm compiling something like a driver on Solaris.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

`Jython : 2.5.1

Solaris : 5.9

MySQL - 5.1.42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`zxJDBC`](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html) and JDBC instead of an external DB-API adapter.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check that out. So I don't repeat this in another question. What should I use if needed a plain python driver for mysql  to use with django ?